# Does the Android 6.0 runtime permission check callback have to be handled in the Activity?

Tags: android, callback, android-6.0-marshmallow

Basically, I want to create a wrapper for my application to handle the runtime permission checks using my own callback.  I want to do some equivalent of adding a new callback to the `requestPermissions` method or Overriding the `Activity` method `onRequestPermissionsResult` in this function so I don't have to worry about application states.  Is this possible?

I know that there are other ways to manage this using the `requestCode` and `Fragment`s but I'm just curious about this as a possibility.

See example:

```
    interface IPermissionResponse {
        void permissionGranted();
        void providePermissionRationale();
        void permissionDenied();
    }

    private final static int REQUEST_INTERNET = 1;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static void checkInternetPermission(Activity activity, boolean giveRationale, IPermissionResponse callback) {

        if(!platformVersionCheck()){
            // not android M, proceed with permission granted
            callback.permissionGranted();
            return;
        }

        Context nContext = activity.getApplicationContext();

        // android M things...
        if(nContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // permission granted
            callback.permissionGranted();
        } else {
            // permission not granted

            // provide additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional information about the use of the permission
            if(giveRationale && activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){
              callback.providePermissionRationale();
            }

            // request the permission
            activity.requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_INTERNET
            /*, new IRequestPermissionCallback(){
            // create new callback here
                // if accepted, callback.permissionGranted
                // if denied, callback.permissionDenied
            }*/);

            // OR SOMETHING LIKE

            // handle the result callback ?????
//            activity.onRequestPermissionsResult(........){
//                // create new callback here
//                // if accepted, callback.permissionGranted
//                // if denied, callback.permissionDenied
//            };
        }
    }

    private static boolean platformVersionCheck() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }
```

Comment: Under the covers, `requestPermissions()` is handled by `startActivityForResult()`, and so the result will go back to the same component that called `requestPermissions()`. There is nothing you can do to really change that.

Comment: I assumed this to be the case.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't any callback. To have an automatic management you can look here: [Permission library](https://github.com/baldapps/PermissionLibrary)

Comment: That's what I assumed and this is extremely unfortunate.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The [RxPermission](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) maybe helpful.

```
RxPermissions.getInstance(activity)
    .request(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .subscribe(new Action1<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Boolean grant) {
            if (grant) {
                save(); // granted
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(mContainer, getString(R.string.no_permission),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```